# How Measure works in PowerBI when displayed it with Chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have been exploring on Time Series graph for one of my requirements. And I came across the following link to display the time-series chart. My requirement is similar to the one requested in the forum where I need to know No. of visitors to a coffee shop at various times.

PowerBI Reference Link: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Start-and-end-time/m-p/762708#M367547

My data is the following

[image]

And I would like to have the chart displayed like below

[image]

I got the chart based (link how I expected) on the advice from the forum. In the response they want me to add the following measure. This measure helped me to get the result as I expected. But I am not sure how this measure works especially the MinVal and MaxVal of the TimeTable would remains the same through out. And also the filter EntryTime<=MinTime confuses me a lot. I believe MinTime would be 12:00 A.M and as per the data EntryTime would never be less than MinTime. Can any one please explain how this measure works in this context.

```
Number of clients 2 =
VAR vMinVal =
    MIN ( TimeTable[Value] )
VAR vMaxVal =
    MAX ( TimeTable[Value] )
VAR vNumberOfClients =
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED ( ClientsTbl ),
            ClientsTbl[Entry Time] <= vMinVal
                && ClientsTbl[Exit Time] >= vMaxVal
        )
    )
RETURN
    vNumberOfClients
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this measure to work, TimeTable[Value] has to be on the axis. Then when the measure is evaluated, TimeTable[Value] acts as a context filter. (If that means nothing to you, try reading through [this helpful reference card](https://p3adaptive.com/2015/10/giving-back-steal-this-reference-card/).) Instead of using all the values on TimeTable in your measure, TimeTable is filtered to just the value on the axis.

So the code:

```
ClientsTbl[Entry Time] <= vMinVal
&& ClientsTbl[Exit Time] >= vMaxVal
```

for the point on the axis at 6:00am would evaluate as:

```
ClientsTbl[Entry Time] <= 6:00am
&& ClientsTbl[Exit Time] >= 6:00am
```

As you can see, it is a little misleading using variables named "min" and "max", and your formula doesn't need two variables--one would work fine.